# Device will not acquire network address AirPort Extreme

Tags: network, time-capsule, airport

I have an 3TB Time Capsule that is connected to Pace cable modem providing internet access.

I have a device Popcorn Hour, and NMT - Network Media Tank, that only had a wired internet connection, that is physically difficult to reach by cat-6 cable.  My solution was to use an Airport Extreme, configured to extend a "wireless" network.

The issue I'm having is that the NMT is not obtaining an IP address on the 192 network.  It shows a 169 address.  I did test the device physically attached to the 3TB Time Capsule and it acquired a 192 address.

So my question is why is the Airport Extreme not allocating a 192 address for the wired connection.

BTW: a `netstat` command to display the routing table did not show the device at the 169 address.

Comment: You don't need a WiFi extender.  What you need is a *bridge*.  The difference is that an extender "extends" the WiFi coverage, where as a bridge connects media of different types to your network - in this case, Ethernet (wired) to WiFi (wireless).

Comment: Before going any further, you want to confirm that your NMT is functional and *can* connect to your network.  Bring it local to your router, plug it into one of the LAN ports and ensure it gets an IP.  If everything works, then proceed to hooking it up to the APE.  If it fails locally, then we've narrowed the problem down to the NMT and removed the APE from the equation.

Comment: 1. By connecting the NMT to the 3TB Time Capsule, which is the primary router, I did verify that it can connect.  Leaving the configuration of the Airport Extreme at fault.

Comment: 2. I reset the Airport Extreme, 5 second - hard reset and I'm still stuck.

Comment: The "Internet" tab is set to "Connect Using:" DHCP.   "Wirteless" tab is set to "Extend a wireless network". And "Network" tab "Router Mode: Off (Bridge Mode).  Everything on that tab is grayed out.  The only way I can get the network tab UNgrayed is to set the wireless tab network mode to off.

Comment: When the network is OFF and bridge mode is one the ariport extreme throws two errors and is not visable from the primary network.

Comment: On the wireless tab, what other modes do you have?  What are the errors?   I done have AirPorts anymore mostly because they’re no longer supported by Apple and were a pain....so I’m going off memory.